# Can't merge in Perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have a branch that I created using `p4 integrate` but now the merge isn't behaving how I expect.  When I merge, I get the following:

```
$ p4 merge -n ISSUE-49/... trunk/...
...
//depot/products/theProduct/trunk/some/directory/somefile.conf#1 - sync/delete from //depot/products/theProduct/ISSUE-49/some/directory/somefile.conf#1
...
```

That file was added on the ISSUE-49 branch (not deleted) so I don't understand why it wants to delete it.

When I try and use `p4 integrate`, I get:

```
$ p4 integrate -n ISSUE-49/... trunk/...
...
//depot/products/theProduct/trunk/some/directory/somefile.conf#1 - branch/sync from //depot/products/theProduct/ISSUE-49/some/directory/somefile.conf#1
...
```

It looks like it's trying to do a branch instead of a merge.  Is it?  How can I safely merge my changes from ISSUE-49 back into trunk?

I am trying to do this from the command-line on Linux using `p4 2012.1`.  I have `p4v 2013.3` on my Windows machine.  I could use that if it would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "merge" operation doesn't necessary always result in an "integrate" revision -- it depends on the current state of the target file and the changes made in the source file.

A "branch" revision is the first revision of a new file that is created as a copy from some other file.  A "delete" revision represents a file that does not actually exist (usually this is a placeholder for a file that previously existed and has been deleted, but it can also be a placeholder for a file that has never existed).

The difference between "p4 merge" and "p4 integrate" is that with "p4 integrate" the file is opened for "branch" immediately rather than scheduling a resolve.  If you run "p4 merge" followed by "p4 resolve -am" the file will be opened for "branch" exactly as if you'd run "p4 integrate".

Summary: everything is fine.  Since the file does not exist in the trunk yet, a normal merge from ISSUE-49 will create it in the trunk as a new file.  Whether you run "p4 integrate"+"p4 resolve" or "p4 merge"+"p4 resolve", the file will be opened for "branch", which is the action that creates it as a new file that is identical to the ISSUE-49 file.

Comment: You're right.  It looks like it's fine.  The information that Perforce displays is quite confusing.  Thanks for the help.